# SSAS Standard deviation calculation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I am building a little cube and have a problem with creating the calculations.

[image: Cube View]

All in all I want some values based on the Plugin.
As an example I want the standard deviation of the execution time.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT Plugin.PluginId, AVG(Task.ExecutionTimeMs) AS Mean
 , STDEVP(Task.ExecutionTimeMs) AS [Standard Deviation]
 , STDEVP(Task.ExecutionTimeMs) * STDEVP(Task.ExecutionTimeMs) AS Variance
FROM Task
```

In my Analysis Project I created an calculation with the following expression:

```
STDEVP( [Finished Tasks], [Measures].[Execution Time Ms Sum] )
```

which didn't work.
I tried some other functions (MAX,AVG) but none worked as intended so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

What is the correct way to create a such measures?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about SSAS Multidimensional then StDevP MDX is a pretty expensive function to use in your case because it has to calculate at the leaf level (fact table row level or Task level in your case). If you have more than a couple thousand tasks I would recommend an optimization which performs well and gets the right number.

This idea is from this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/956ca1cc-0d38-42ed-9891-d81cd9722424/aggregatefunction-stddev-standard-deviation-for-measure-on-microsoft-analysis-services-2005-or?forum=sqlanalysisservices).

> 1. load in a simple SUM measure (x) - the sum of fact column (aggregated in the cube)
> 2. load in a simple SUM measure of x squared (x2) - sum of square of fact column (aggregated in the cube)
> 3. load in a counter called cnt - count of a fact column (aggregated in the cube)
>
> [The MDX calculation would then be:]
>
> ((x2 - ((x^2)/cnt))/cnt)^0.5